# firebase crashlytics not have readable report

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, crash-reports

I have crashlytics on my project about two years and it work fine until 2 month ago
in last month reports are not readable and return wrong line like below image
I add this crashlytics proguard rules but its not fix

```
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class com.google.firebase.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.firebase.crashlytics.**
```

how do i do to fix it?
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZVwO.png

Comment: Can you make sure all of the information in this section is in your proguard file https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=android#keep_obfuscated_build_variants

Comment: yes i am sure from this

Comment: Please reachout to Firebase Support